# What is considered a concurrent query in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

We are running into quota limits for a small data set which is less than 1Gb in Bigquery. Google cloud gives us no indication of what queries are running on the backend which isn't allowing us to tune the setup. We have a Bigquery dataset and a dashboard built in data studio which is querying on the data set.

I've used relational databases like Oracle in the past and they have excellent tooling to diagnose issues. But with Bigquery, I feel like I am staring into the dark.

I'd appreciate any help/pointers you can give.

Comment: You can list current jobs either using the API or with the command line client using `bq ls -j --all`.

Comment: Are you hitting the limit when using the Data Studio dashboard? If yes, exactly what message are you seeing?

Comment: Below is the error:You've exceeded the quota policy for this data set.
concurrent queries
Error ID: 455a4526

Answer (score 1):

The **concurrent queries** limit makes reference to the number of statements that are executed simultaneously in BigQuery. The [quota limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs) for on-demand, interactive queries is 100 concurrent queries (updated).

Based on this, it is seems that your **Data Studio** is hitting this quota when running your reports in which case is suggested to re-design your dashboard build in order to avoid exceeding those limits.

Additionally, you can use the [bq ls -j -a PROJECTNAME](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_ls) command to list the jobs that have been run in your project in order to identify the queries you need to work with, as well mentioned by [Elliott Brossard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6253347/elliott-brossard)

Comment: Thank you. We did fix the dashboard and were able to get around the concurrent query limits.